# Android - TabActivity inner Activities

Tags: android, service, tabactivity

i'm just struggling around with a TabActivity in my android app. I have a Service that holds a tcp socket connection to a server. The TabActivity has a connection to that service. Because all Activities that are created in the tabs need also this connection. To get a running TabActivity i looked at [Hello TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). I've read, that these SubActivities are a problem, because the interaction of this activities doesn't work that good.

My Question would be, if it's possible to get a connection between the TabActivity and the SubActivities, or would it be a better approach, to take just one activity like it is handled in [this Tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59). 
The problem that i see, is the size of the TabActivity, because you have to deal with the logic of all SubActivities in that class.

Answer (score 1):

you can get access with following code:

```
ListActivity currentActivity = (ListActivity) mActivity.getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
```